# Which are the corresponding parameters for rect and pivot in exporting an editor defined sprite, to be re-created using Sprite.Create?

Tags: unity, sprites

Which are the corresponding parameters for rect and pivot in exporting an editor defined sprite, to be re-created using [Sprite.Create](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html)?

I've tried both .rect and .[textureRect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite-textureRect.html) for storing the editor defined rect for a sprite and also .pivot, but it seems Sprite.Create is not able to re-create the sprite properly(?)

Comment: What sprite are you trying to recreate, how are you trying to recreate it, and how do the results you get differ from what you get in-editor?  Show us screenshots and code that demonstrate your problem.

Comment: it appears to be a unit mismatch between sprite.pivot and the pivot used in Sprite.Create

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `Sprite.Create` takes a non-pixel based unit value for pivot and `sprite.pivot` is a pixel based unit.

For example, `sprite.pivot` for a (1000x500) image would be `(500,250)` but `Sprite.Create` wants `(0.5,0.5)`

Comment: Helpfully, [this is explicitly described in the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html): "The third argument pivot determines what becomes the center of the Sprite. This is a `Vector2` relative to the `rect` where `Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f)` is the bottom left and `Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f)` is the top right."

Comment: sprite.pivot should be in the same units

Comment: Not according to [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite-pivot.html): "Location of the Sprite's center point in the Rect on the original Texture, specified in **pixels**"

Comment: well, this discrepancy is quite annoying

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as Accepted if it worked for you.